# Create MYSQL table with columns from 1 - 150

Tags: mysql

Need to create a table which the first row has numbers 1,2,3,..,150 ( so each number has their own column ) and the next row either contains zero or is empty.

I did a script but not working out:

```
CREATE TABLE voting (
    1 INT,
    2 INT,
    3 INT,
    4 INT,
    5 INT,
    6 INT,
    //numbers redacted
    149 INT,
    150 INT
);
INSERT INTO voting VALUES (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

I get error #1064.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _'What am I doing wrong?'_ - In SQL terms, just about everything. Start by describing what this is for, and be open to a completely different approach.

Comment: @HoboSapiens completely open as I am a newbie. I'm trying to have 150 columns ( id's ) for items so when I `INSERT` with mysql, I just have to match the column for the id, and not have it `UPDATE` every time. 

Each row for each column will get `INSERT` from a PHP Form.

Is this not possible?

Comment: Numbers are not valid column names.  In general, multiple columns whose names are sequential numbers are usually a sign of poor database design.  I'd suggest you delete this question and ask another about how to represent the entities you want to work with.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If I do come up with a different ID algorithm, is it still a poor approach?

Comment: I asked how to approach this problem and got -10 bombed so I had to come up with something myself.

Comment: As it stands, this is a terrible idea. Either come up with a new one or forget about using an RDBMS for this problem.

Comment: @ParsaPierre - data should be searched for within a column. You should not be searching through multiple columns for any 1 piece of data. What is the data you're trying to work with, and what has lead you to the conclusion that such a table would be a good solution to the problem? Understanding each of these questions puts answerers in a better position to assist you.

Comment: @enhzflep I'm trying to have community vote on some items, have the script collect their votes, sum up their votes and display it. Having columns be as many as the items and just having `INSERT`  the only logical thing that crossed my mind with my level of coding knowledge.

Comment: @ParsaPierre - Ahhhhh! No freakin' way man. **Q:** What if extra items are added after your code is finished **A:** you're screwed! You have to change the table structure just for extra data, but no functional change. Nah, just have three columns. 1 for a unique identifier of the vote, 1 for the id of the item and another for the vote itself.  | voteId | itemId | voteValue |

Comment: @enhzflep and when I take data from PHP, I just put `id` in `voteId`, and everytime anyone votes a new one, there will be a new row. Then I `SELECT` ID when echoing? Right?

Q: How do I put an ID for the vote?

Comment: @ParsaPierre - Just make the `voteId` field an auto_increment one that doesn't need a value. Then, all you need to do is submit the `itemId` and the `vote` to the SQL. I.e `insert into voteTable (itemId, voteValue) values (1, 5);` - You can then use SQL to total the number of votes cast on any one item or even to work out what the average vote for an item is. Not sure how you want to display your data, so can't really answer if you'd `SELECT` ID or not. `select count(*) from voteTable where itemId=2` would tell you the number of votes cast on item 2, for instance.

Comment: @enhzflep Thank you so much. People like you are why I like trying to code. Thanks !

Comment: @ParsaPierre - you're most welcome. Working out how to research the documentation takes time - none of us were terribly good at it initially. Right back atcha - responses like yours are why I enjoy trying to help. :) After all, we all stand on the shoulders of those that came before us.